# How do I make a 800x800 console window with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-console

I've recently been making a simple text based game in python 3.9 and I want to make it so when you run the .exe it will open a console window that is 800x800 or whatever ratio I want to put in. Could anyone help me do this please!

Comment: `text based game` doesn't have a pixel-based resolution. A terminal only has line x column

Comment: If the current process does not effectively own the console window, as determined by `GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetConsoleWindow(), &pid)`, then it should respawn itself with a new console. Then and only then is it reasonable to change the window size and screen buffer dimensions via `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx`.

Answer (score 0):

The only option that i can think of its to run tour program in **PowerShell**, this one can resize it self with something like this

```
$pshost = get-host
$pswindow = $pshost.ui.rawui
$newsize = $pswindow.buffersize
$newsize.height = 3000
$newsize.width = 150
$pswindow.buffersize = $newsize
$newsize = $pswindow.windowsize
$newsize.height = 50
$newsize.width = 150
$pswindow.windowsize = $newsize
```

I get this code from [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-expand-the-width-of-the-windows-powershell-console/)

You can call this commands inside python with `OS` module.

I couldnt test the code cause *#teamLinux*.